# How to run two versions of static website simultaneously for A/B testing?

Tags: html, testing, usability

For example I have a very simple website only HTML/CSS/Javascript based no php,.net, ruby is being used. Some visitors to my site should see version “A,” while others see version “B.

Site is hosted on Apache server

Comment: Are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: I would like if there is any free tool which can do this work

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to run Apache as a load balancer, "balancing" between the two different versions of the site (which are their own vhosts running on other ports). When someone connects, apache will randomly direct them to version A or version B of the site. You can use [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) to do this. It also supports "sticky" balancing: that is, you can set a cookie so that once a client gets into version A, they're always directed to version A (and likewise with version B).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want .htaccess:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html
- http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml

Answer (score 0):

One way is by analyzing the IP Address or range.

Create list of IP Address/Range

```
$ips = array(
    "a" => array( 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', ....),
    "b" => array( 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', ....),
);
```

Now, use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and switch the domain

```
if(in_array($ips['a'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    header("location: website.com/a");
} else {
    header("location: website.com/b");
}
exit;
```